# Is __attribute__((constructor)) guaranteed to be called exactly once?

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

Are GCC shared-library constructors and destructors, defined with `__attribute__((constructor))` and `__attribute__((destructor))`, guaranteed to run exactly once? The documentation seems to imply that they will be run at least once, but doesn't mention anything about more than once.

In other words, if I do an operation in the constructor that must be done only once, do I need to protect it like so:

```
static gboolean constructor_has_run = FALSE;
if(!constructor_has_run) {
    do_operation();
    constructor_has_run = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: In practice I think this is always guaranteed, but it would be nice if GCC documented this better.

Comment: Yes - constructor is called once before main() and destructor is called once after.

Comment: Obvious with simple case, but with `dlopen` it becomes far less so.

Comment: It's called "constructor", not "function that is called an unspecified positive number of times". The latter is not what constructors normally do. The intent is crystal clear. If you think it should be explicitly mentioned in the documentation, file a bug against the documentation.

Comment: The fact that shared library constructors are re-run every time you load a library (and it is legal to load the same library twice, you can also link to one and load it manually, possibly several times) somewhat blurs this "obvious intent". But testing on Windows and Linux shows that GCC only ever calls functions with the constructor attribute once (let's hope this is true for all other platforms, too). The compiler seems to add code for that.

Comment: @Damon You load the library, the constructors get called. You unload it, the destructors get called. You load it again, the constructors get called. That's how constructors do. If you need to do something else, constructors are not your friends (`gboolean constructor_has_run` will be `FALSE` again on subsequent library loads). If GCC ever does something else it would be a bug.

Comment: @n.m.: It is legal to load a library twice without unloading it first. Under Windows, `DLLMain` is called once _for each thread_ every time you load the library. `_init` is guaranteed to be called only once under Linux, but that is not necessarily so for every system. Still, under GCC, constructors (which are called from `DLLMain` and `_init`, respectively) run only once. No matter what you do, and no matter on what system I've tried.

Comment: @Damon "It is legal to load a library twice without unloading it first". If you mean "call dlopen twice" then yes, you can do that. The library is not actually loaded when you do that, only the reference count is bumped.

Answer (score 2):

An observation that might be useful if someone wants to use such functions in headers: if a function is defined like

```
__attribute__((constructor)) inline void fn()
{ ... }
```

in N translation units, it will be called N times.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `__attribute__((constructor))` it will be called at the beginning of the execution.

So you don't have to protect as you have mentioned above.

If you mention too its not wrong

For more Info on  `__attribute__((constructor))` you can take a look at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time debugging some unusual behavior I was seeing with a destructor, the answer here is "it depends".

In a normal situation, the constructor and destructor would only be called once.  However when shared libraries are involved, it's possible for the constructor and destructor to be called multiple times.

I'm working on some unit tests and was statically linking directly against the module containing the constructor. The link is also bringing in shared libraries that end up loading a second copy of the module that resides within a dependent shared library context.

The result is the constructor and destructor are called once for the version of the module residing in the main() image and once for the version of the module within a loaded shared library.